# i am getting Error While Export my Android Application From Eclipse which use android-support-v4.jar with Proguard

Tags: android, jar, proguard

Can any one help me which i am using ProGuard in my Android Application i am getting Following Error While i am Signed it to Export.

Here what my Console Show me.

```
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Note: there were 95 duplicate class definitions.
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find superclass or interface android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb: can't find referenced method 'void invalidateOptionsMenu()' in class android.app.Activity
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb: can't find referenced method 'void dump(java.lang.String,java.io.FileDescriptor,java.io.PrintWriter,java.lang.String[])' in class android.app.Activity
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find referenced class android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find referenced class android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MenuCompatHoneycomb: can't find referenced method 'void setShowAsAction(int)' in class android.view.MenuItem
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]          or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the options 
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' and/or
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:308) 
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:210)
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:85)
[2011-11-03 16:07:52 - AndroidViewPager]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

I think in jar may be some thing not proper.
How to give specify additional library jars i am using following Proguard.cfg file

```
  optimizationpasses 5

 -dontpreverify
 -verbose

  -libraryjars 'E:\Himanshu\AndroidViewPager\libs\android-support-v4.jar'
  -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
  -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

 -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
 -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
 -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
 -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
 -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
 -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

 -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

 -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

  -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

  -keepclassmembers enum * {
      public static **[] values();
     public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
 }

  -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
  }
```

Comment: Don't known why get downvote ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following to proguard.cfg worked for me. I think its because you are not using honeycomb but the compatibility library has some honeycomb specific things in it.

```
-dontwarn CompatHoneycomb -keep class android.support.v4. { *; }
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn **ActivityCompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **MenuCompatHoneycomb
```

Also, remove

```
libraryjars 'E:\Himanshu\AndroidViewPager\libs\android-support-v4.jar'
```

Comment: you make me to remove libraryjars that means does it will make optimize for jars i use.

Comment: Only a suggestion. Leave it if it still works for you. I thought that was your attempt to fix the error you were experiencing.

Comment: The -libraryjars option is causing all those duplicate class definitions, since the build script already includes all jars in the libs directory as program jars (which are then optimized). You should remove the option indeed.

Comment: @EricLafortune Thanks For Comment ,so i don't need to provide -libraryjars option in my android project right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out, I needed to update the project's build target.

Looks like the version of android-support-v4.jar needs to match the project build target version in order for proguard to work. In my case, `android-support-v4.jar revision 10` needs to have build target `Android 4.1.2 (API 16)` set up in **Package Explorer Project > Properties > Android**.

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, I still have `android:targetSdkVersion="13"` set. This setting seems to have no connection to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

method void `setShowAsAction(int)` is not available in compatibility library.
Try using menu's xml file parameters

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@[+][package:]id/resource_name"
      android:title="string"
      android:titleCondensed="string"
      android:icon="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource_name"
      android:onClick="method name"
      android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" |
                            "collapseActionView"]
      .../>
</menu>
```

Comment: i am not getting where should i have to do can you give some more hint

Comment: Look at this tutorial on how to use Menu.xml to add action item to the Action Bar which is backward compatible. http://android-codelabs.appspot.com/resources/tutorials/honeypad/ex1.html Step 3

Comment: @ also i need that library for only use of ViewPager and PagerAdapter

Comment: @But in my app i use only onCreateOptionsMenu